# How to install Ubuntu on Lenovo Ideapad system with preinstalled Windows?

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation

Windows boot in UEFI mod using Windows Boot Manager. Pendrives and live DVDs are detected in Legacy mod only.

So how can I install Ubuntu 16.04 on my system?

I have tried using Rufus to make live USB but it did not run on UEFI boot mode.

Comment: Run Rufus executable drive straight from usb not uefi mode usb.

Comment: @neuronet Please convert your comment into an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have done this a few times, there are usually a couple of options given for booting to the USB: you can either run the USB on UEFI boot mode, or just boot to the USB directly. If you have created an executable using Rufus, just start from the USB stick directly.